# django-lazysignup not working

Tags: django, django-views

I installed django-lazysignup as described in http://django-lazysignup.readthedocs.org/en/latest/install.html with Django==1.5:

```
# settings.py
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.auth',
    [...]
    'lazysignup',
)

# added it myself, since it wasn't in the settings
AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
  'django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend',
  'lazysignup.backends.LazySignupBackend',
)

# project urls.py
url(
    regex=r'^convert/',
    view=include('lazysignup.urls', namespace='lazysignup')
),

# app views.py
from lazysignup.decorators import allow_lazy_user

@allow_lazy_user
def my_view(request):
    [...]
```

Now, if I go to this view no user is generated in the lazysignup_lazyuser table. It just stays empty.

Do I have to install anything else from django auth for it to work? I've tried to use the @login_required decorator from django, but that doesn't work either:

```
# app views.py
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def my_view(request):
    [...]
```

Do I need LOGIN_URL (which is not in seetings.py)? Any hint would be appreciated :)

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue solved: Django user authentication was missing (Login, Logout etc.)